# Get milliseconds by next Saturday

Tags: java, date, datetime, milliseconds

I am developing a weekly event, but I need to get the milliseconds (unix timestamp) by next Saturday. How can I do that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html this will probably be good reading for your problem :)

Comment: Nitpick: Unix timestamps are in seconds; they may be different sizes, and in theory even floating-point, but always seconds. *Java* timestamps are milliseconds from the same *epoch* (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) as Unix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 create a calendar

```
 Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
```

2 create another calendar, set it to midnight and move day by day until you hit Saturday

```
    Calendar calNextSat = Calendar.getInstance();
    calNextSat.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    calNextSat.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calNextSat.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    while(calNextSat.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY){
        calNextSat.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    System.out.println(calNextSat.getTimeInMillis() - calNow.getTimeInMillis());
```

handle the scenario if it is already Saturday you would get <=0 result

Comment: You can also look into a library called Jodatime (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) whose main purpose is to fix the issues with Java's native time stuff.

Comment: @shieldstroy  what is the issue in native time stuff ?

Comment: It's just generally hard to use. It works fine, but most people prefer JodaTime's API.

Comment: This code ignores the crucial issue of time zone, implicitly depending on the JVM’s [current default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-) time zone which can be changed at any moment by any code in any thread of this JVM. Better to specify the desired/expected [time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html).

Comment: It dosen't look like this supports 24-hour format, what do I do then?

Answer (score 3):

> I am developing a weekly event

Using milliseconds for this kind of date-time tracking will probably lead you astray. For example, because of Daylight Saving Time (DST) and other anomalies, a day is not always 24-hours long and therefore a week is not always ( ( 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 ) * 7 ) milliseconds long.

## Joda-Time or java.time

I suggest learning how to use a sophisticated date-time library. In Java that means either:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (built into Java 8, inspired by Joda-Time).

## Time Zone

The time zone is crucial in determining the day and day-of-week. Use [proper time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never the 3 or 4 letter codes.

## Example Code To Get Next Day-Of-Week

Here is example code using Joda-Time 2.7.

Get the time zone you desire/expect. If working in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), use the constant `DateTimeZone.UTC`.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
```

Get the date-time value you need. Here I am using the current moment.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now( zone );
```

Specify the future day-of-week you want. Note that Joda-Time uses the sensible # 1 for first day of week, rather than zero-based counting found in java.util.Calendar. First day of week is Monday, per international norms and standards (not Sunday as is common in United States).

```
int dayOfWeek = DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY;
```

The `withDayOfWeek` command may go back in time. So we use a [ternary operator (`?:`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to make sure we go forwards in time by adding a week as needed.

```
DateTime future = ( dateTime.getDayOfWeek() < dayOfWeek )
        ? dateTime.withDayOfWeek( dayOfWeek )
        : dateTime.plusWeeks( 1 ).withDayOfWeek( dayOfWeek );
```

You may want to adjust the time-of-day to the first moment of the day to emphasize the focus on the day rather than a particular moment within the day.

```
future = future.withTimeAtStartOfDay(); // Adjust time-of-day to first moment of the day to stress the focus on the entire day rather than a specific moment within the day. Or use `LocalDate` class.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "Next day # " + dayOfWeek + " after " + dateTime + " is " + future );
```

When run.

```
Next day # 6 after 2015-04-18T16:03:36.146-04:00 is 2015-04-25T00:00:00.000-04:00
```

## Until Then

The code above gives us the desired future point in time (next Saturday).

If all you really want is the number of milliseconds between now and then, subtract between each one’s internal count-from-[epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) in milliseconds. Note the use of 64-bit `long` rather than 32-bit `int` when tracking times as milliseconds.

```
long elapsedMilliseconds = ( future.getMillis() - dateTime.getMillis() );
```

Note that if you are doing this work in java.time rather Joda-Time, be aware that internally java.time uses [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) rather than [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). You can find milliseconds-savvy methods as I recall. Or divide nanoseconds by a million (yes, million not thousand, as [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) are in between.

You may want to more intelligently represent the span of time between now and then. Joad-Time offers three classes for representing a span of time in various manners:

- [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) (a pair of fixed points on the time line)
- [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) (a number of months, days, hours, and such)
- [`Duration`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) (a number of milliseconds).

Example code, again Joda-Time 2.7.

```
Interval interval = new Interval( dateTime , future );
Period period = interval.toPeriod();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "interval: " + interval );
System.out.println( "period: " + period );
```

When run.

```
interval: 2015-04-18T16:17:45.109-04:00/2015-04-25T00:00:00.000-04:00
period: P6DT7H42M14.891S
```

Notice the String representation format used by default for the Period value. That format is standard, part of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), called a [`duration`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) in their terminology. That format is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates the date portion from the time portion.

Both Joda-Time and java.time use ISO 8601 as their defaults in both parsing and generating string representations of date-time values.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to get the current day of the week. And you could subtract it like,

```
public static int daysUntilSaturday(Date d) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(d);
    return 7 - cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
}
```

Then you can perform *simple* arithmetic like

```
/*
 * 1000 milliseconds in a second, 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in
 * an hour, 24 hours in a day.
 */
final long millisecondsPerDay = 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24;
System.out.println((daysUntilSaturday(new Date()) * millisecondsPerDay)
        + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: you could skip that switch case by one liner, also you might have to take care of 00:00 hours that is when saturday starts

Comment: @JigarJoshi Even better! :)